# How to add two static rows using react js and antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am currently using antd table i know how to add one static row in antd table
Now i want to group two data into static rows like one having jobs should end up below jobs and one having invoice should end up below invoice Like This
[image]

I have currently did it like this :

```
const columns = [
        {
          title: "Date Due",
          dataIndex: "date_due",
          sorter: (a, b) => {
            return a?.date_due?.localeCompare(b?.date_due);
          },
    
          children: [
            {
              title: "Jobs",
              dataIndex: "job",
              key: "date_scheduled",
              render: (text, record) => (
                  record?.date_scheduled
              ),
            },
          ],
  children: [
    {
      title: "Invoice",
      dataIndex: "invoice",
      key: "date_scheduled",
      render: (text, record) => record?.date_scheduled,
    },
  ],
          sorter: (a, b) => {
            return a?.date_scheduled?.localeCompare(b?.date_scheduled);
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Status",
          children: [
            {
              dataIndex: "status",
              key: "status",
              render: (text, record) => (
                  record?.status
              ),
            },
          ],
          sorter: (a, b) => {
            return a?.status?.localeCompare(b?.status);
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Amount",
          children: [
            {
              dataIndex: "amount",
              key: "amount_due",
              render: (text, record) => (
                  record?.amount_due
              ),
            },
          ],
          sorter: (a, b) => {
            return a?.amount_due?.localeCompare(b?.amount_due);
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Actions",
          children: [
            {
              dataIndex: "action",
              key: "action",
              render: (text, record) => (
                <>
                <Button
                  className="default-btn"
                  icon={<CloseOutlined />}
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#D15B47",
                    color: "#ffffff",
                    borderColor: "#87B87F",
                    borderRadius: "10px",
                  }}
                />
              </>
              ),
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
```

But with this i can get only one static row like this
[image]
The last children is shown here
And i also i couldn't add No jobs added to the bill and no invoice added to the bill if there ain't any information

So can any one please help me with this
Thankyou in advance

Comment: where are you adding invoices in your code?

Comment: No currently i dont know where to add invoice

Comment: But i have tried adding it in the children array bit it is not working